# Which convergence test should I use to test this functional series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(nx)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The following series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^ncos(nx)=\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)...$$

is obviously divergent when $x=0$. At that point, we have the Grandi series $1-1+1-1+1...$

when $x=\pi/2$, the series is also a Grandi series.

I am teaching myself convergent tests that are used in Calculus 2 right now so I wonder if I can apply any of those tests to test for convergence of this series?

How can I prove that this series is divergent for all $x$?

I haven't learnt Fourier analysis so more advanced explanation will be way over my head.

I also not skill at the integral test, so perhaps a bit of an elaborated answer will help.

Comment: For a series to converge, its terms must tend to zero.

Comment: The sum is the real part of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-e^{ix}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series diverges for any $x\in\Bbb R$. That's so because, if $x\in\Bbb R$, you do not have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\cos(nx)=0$. Note that if we had that, then it would also be true that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(nx)=0,\tag1$$which would imply that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(2nx)=0$. But$$\cos(2nx)=2\cos^2(nx)-1$$and so we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cos^2(nx)-1=0$, which is impossible, since we are assuming $(1)$, from which it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cos^2(nx)-1=-1$.

Comment: How do we evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cos^2(nx)-1$.

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(nx)=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}2\cos^2(nx)-1=2\times0-1=-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit slow, but why $\cos(nx)$ has anything to do with $\cos(2nx)$

Comment: Because the sequence $\bigl(\cos(2nx)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of the sequence $\bigl(\cos(nx)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$

Comment: You mean $\cos(2x)$?

Comment: No, I wrote what I meant.

Comment: Man, perhaps I am not that ready to tackle this problem. I am lost at $(cos(2nx))$ being a subsequence of $cos(nx)$

Comment: The sequence $\bigl(\cos(nx)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is$$\cos(x),\color{red}{\cos(2x)},\cos(3x),\color{red}{\cos(4x)},\ldots$$and those terms in red are the sequence $\bigl(\cos(2nx)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: Ok, I got you now. Thank you

Comment: I have a question, why don't you calculate the limit for $\cos(nx)$ as $x$ reaches infinity, but instead choose to show that $\cos(2nx)$ cannot be 0? Because it is harder?

Comment: No. It's because $x$ is a number which was fixed at the beginning of the problem. It doesn't go to $\infty$; it just stays there. On the other hand, we are dealing with the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\cos(nx)$, and so we are dealing with $\cos(x), \cos(2x),\cos(3x)\ldots$

Comment: If we think of this series as a functional series in which x takes the value from negative to positive infinity, and n is an index that goes from 1 to infinity, does this change our conclusion at all? Because that's how I think about this functional series.

Comment: No, it changes nothing at all.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos Thank you for your patience. Your argument is very succinct and clever. I understand it now.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I have done so. I did try it but there is a policy of waiting for 7 minutes so I forgot.